# ¿Por qué se incluye beta?

Tags: discusión

Este foro se llama "Spanish Language Beta".  Me pregunto ¿por qué se incluye "beta"?  ¿Es que este foro permanece en un estado de comienzo?

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta a su pregunta está en el [Help Center](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta).
Traducido a español:

> ### ¿Qué significa "beta"?
>
> Este sitio fue creado por un [proceso abierto y democratico](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) en [Stack Exchange Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  Los sitios creados por este proceso empiezan en “beta”, que significa que el sitio todavía está siendo definido y construido. Hay varias diferencias entre sitios beta y no beta en nuestra red:
>
> - Todos los sitios beta tienen el mismo diseño temporal. Cuando el sitio ya no sea beta, tendrá un diseño gráfico personalizado, construido con el aporte de la comunidad.
> - Los umbrales de reputación para los [privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/privileges) son más bajos durante la fase beta para alentar la gobernancia comunitaria.
> - Al inicio de la fase beta, el equipo de Stack Exchange [nombra moderadores](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) hasta que el sitio sea lo suficientemente grande como para soportar [elecciones democráticas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work).
>
> Durante la fase beta, la comunidad colabora para responder a [siete preguntas esenciales](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) para cada sitio de Stack Exchange:
>
> 1. ¿Las preguntas sobre {tema} están dentro o fuera de ámbito?
> 2. ¿Qué debería contener nuestra FAQ?
> 3. ¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar las preguntas sobre {tema}?
> 4. ¿Quiénes deberían ser los moderadores?
> 5. ¿Cuál debe ser la descripción breve del sitio?
> 6. ¿Qué aspecto deberían tener nuestro logotipo y el diseño del sitio?
> 7. ¿Cómo vamos a promover nuestro sitio?
>
> No hay un límite de tiempo para que un sitio permanezca en beta; estará en beta [durante el tiempo necesario para alcanzar la masa crítica](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), con evaluaciones periódicas que ayudarán a que la comunidad sepa a qué atenerse y por dónde hay que trabajar un poco más.

Comment: En lugar de "la comunidad trabaja junto" sugiero dejar simplemente "la comunidad trabaja" ya que me parece que "junto" tiene dos problemas 1) no concuerda: "la comunidad" es femenino "junto" es masculino; debería ser "junta". 2) es redundante; podría tener usarse para dar énfasis, pero resultaría verboso.

Comment: @Ruben concuerdo sobre la redundancia, pero es posible usar en español un adverbio sin afijo, en tal caso, se pone en la forma neutra (que comparte su forma con la masculina). No creo que lo usaría en este contexto, pero existe la posibilidad.

Comment: @guifa: de acuerdo que es posible. Un ejemplo usando "juntar" que me viene a la mente es "ella junto con él..." por el contrario "la comunidad trabaja junto", no me parece apropiado, tal vez sea sólo por cacofonía (las últimas sílabas de `comunidad` y `trabaja` llevan `a`, se escucharía mejor `junta` que `junto`). En fin. Lo "bueno" es que estamos de acuerdo en que en este caso no se use `junto`.

Comment: @walen - I polished your edits a little more but please feel free to roll any or all of them back.

Comment: También tenéis la versión traducida en el Centro de Ayuda de SOes --> [¿Qué significa "beta"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta)